# What is a vasquette?

Tags: google-maps, google-chrome

I've noticed in Google Maps that something is named "vasquette" (and it appears to be the buttons in the top-right)... but what does the name actually mean and where does it come from? Does anyone know?

[image: Screen shot of debugger showing a div with an ID of "vasquette" and the relevant section of the page.]

All I can find is a couple of [tickets that reference it](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=vasquette&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8#safe=active&q=vasquette+chrome).